# Firestore - Get amount of fields in document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with some fields. I want to get the amount of fields.

For Example:

[image]

I will get 5.

My Code:

```
const data = await firestore()
            .collection(groupID)
            .doc('jobs-list')
            .get()
            .then((value) => {
                console.log(value.data.length); // Returns 0
                console.log(value.data()["1"]);
            })
```

I want to log `5`
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way in Firestore to get the count of your fields. You can do it by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method as the result you would get in Firestore is an object. See sample code below:

```
const data = await firestore()
            .collection(groupID)
            .doc('jobs-list')
            .get()
            .then((value) => {
                // This will get the length of the object keys: `5`
                console.log(Object.keys(value.data()).length);
            })
```